# Is there a way to draw anti-aliased lines with Turtle library?

Tags: python-turtle

Is there a way to draw anti-aliased shapes with Turtle Python library? The shapes and lines I draw are always pixelated and have not smooth edges.

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice so we can reproduce the problem and have a basis for discussing where the improvement needs to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik no. But the typical problem making the turtle results look pixelated is the canvas size.

Change the default to something significantly larger and you'll be happy, but the turtle will be slower, as it has to calculate more while walking through the screen:

```py
>>> screensize()
(400, 300)
>>> screen.screensize(2400,1800)
>>> screensize()
(2400, 1800)
```

This is dependent to the graphics engine of the turtle code interpreter. This has been stated for the case that you can scale the Turtle graph window and the canvas will zoom to the best fit in the window. A low canvas resolution will result in ugly blocked lines. (This has been the behavior of the Logo interpreter.)

---

The current Python version of turtle graphic is different:
The canvas will not zoom to fit to the window size. The prior trick will not work. The problem is the graphic interpreter of the python turtle graphic.

The quality of the rendered turtle graph is quite rough. To me it looks like there are some rounding errors prohibiting a smooth result, especially when drawing a circle.

But the advantage of the Python edition is the possibility to export the turtle-painted canvas as EPS file (a vector format), that gives the opportunity to use a professional postscript render of perfect results.

```py
s.getcanvas().postscript(file = "filename.eps")
```

The export will contain only the displayed area of the turtle window, but not the whole defined canvas that possibly scrolled out of the viewport.
This is not a problem, as the data are vector descriptions, so the currently displayed resolution is irrelevant, the EPS will scale without any jaggies. — Here some images to compare the difference in quality. *(To see the intended details, you've to open the images in a separate window.)*

First at a low turtle rendering resolution (canvas size):
[image]

Here at a 10x higher turtle rendering resolution:
[image]
As you  can see:

- for the displayed turtle graph the resolution is of interest, but does not provide a satisfying quality.
- Exported to EPS the quality is perfect (depending on your renderer).
  This is independent of the used canvas size on the screen.

---

To answer the question:

=> You have to export the final canvas of the turtle graph to get satisfying results. For the rendering, the turtle canvas has to fit in your screen, so the export will contain the whole graph.

=> The EPS solution turns anti-aliasing as edge-smoothing workaround obsolete. The edges are optimized due to the EPS rendering.
Regarding the overall quality of the turtle graph (it's more like a preview), I do not expect anti-aliasing as a supported feature.

---

To test this by your own, here the turtle code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import turtle
import math

#### Config 
# Change here only to render at a different scale:
Scale = 1

#### Set the variables:
# Define Base sizes:
ScreenBaseX = 400
ScreenBaseY = 300
BasePen = 1

# Sizes
CanvasX = ScreenBaseX * Scale
CanvasY = ScreenBaseY * Scale
PenSize = BasePen * Scale

# StepWidth:
x = CanvasX / 4
y = CanvasY / 4

# Get the radius of the circle:
r = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)

#### Define file name
filename = "turtle-test_" + str(CanvasX) + "x" + str(CanvasY) + ".eps"

#### Start turtle
s = turtle.getscreen()
s.title("screensize(" + str(CanvasX) + ", " + str(CanvasY) + "), circle(" + str(int(r)) + ")")
s.bgcolor("#dddddd")
s.setup(width = CanvasX, height = CanvasY)
s.screensize(CanvasX, CanvasY)

# Plot the graph:
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.pensize(PenSize)
t.pu(); t.goto(-x, -y); t.pd(); t.fd(2 * x); t.lt(90); t.fd(2 * y); t.lt(90); t.fd(2 * x); t.lt(90); t.fd(2 * y); t.lt(90)
t.pu(); t.goto(0, -y); t.pd(); t.goto(x, 0); t.goto(0, y); t.goto(-x, 0); t.goto(0, -y)
t.pu(); t.goto(0, -r); t.pd(); t.circle(r, 360, 720)
t.pu(); t.goto(0, 0)

# Export to file:
s.getcanvas().postscript(file = filename)

s.exitonclick()
```

Comment: The `screensize()` method changes the backing store size, but the number of pixels drawn doesn't change.  Write a program that just draws a line.  Run it again adding the above code.  Doesn't change the drawing itself on my system.

Comment: @cdlane It's true with the python edition of turtle. I had this problem with the Logo variant a long time ago. There the canvas zoomed with the window size, but didn't change the canvas resolution, so the graph got pixelated when enlarging the window. — Increasing the resolution solved that // Here at Python I now noticed that the problem is different. Here the canvas doesn't link to the window size. But the graphs, especially when drawing circles, are quite rough in appearance. An anti-aliasing, strong enough to compensate would look very blurred. — I extended my answer by a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is that lines aren't anti-aliased:

[image]

but if we grab it and enlarge it:

[image]

it appears there is some sort of anti-aliasing going on.  This may be system dependent.